# How to post process preferences? (I am using spark ALS implicit)

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

I am familiar with the article "Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets" http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf.
I use spark ml ALS implicit to recommend items to users, with parameters Alpha = 30, Rank = 10, RegParam = 0.1. In my dataset there are only users that use more than one item (according to advice given here 
[How to improve my recommendation result? I am using spark ALS implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603789/how-to-improve-my-recommendation-result-i-am-using-spark-als-implicit) )

I use `.recommendForAllUsers` and get preferences `p_ui`. Then I filter only "new" recommendations (combinations user-item that were not in the input dataset). I also filter preferences > 0.01 to get only the most preferable items.

The questions is: how can I postprocess the preferences to make them more similar to "probabilities"? 
(it is a requirement to my program to output some kind of "probability").

Is it a good idea to scale preferences to `[0.5, 1.0]`? (using the formula:

```
scaled_preference = ($"preference"*0.5 + max_preference*0.5 -
  min_preference)/(max_preference - min_preference) ) ?
```